# What is the react-way to handle state that will be impacted by refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So there have been a couple of times now where I have needed to set the state of a component based on properties that are computed at render. As a result, the component is rerendered sometimes. This isn't a huge concern, but it feels hacky and not the "react-way". So I am wondering if someone has a better solution.

So the most recent example is an expandable text component. Similar to the review element on airbnb

[image]

This was fairly easy. But the last part was to detect whether there was any overflow and not display the "More" option if it is unnecessary. The solution I came up with was to check if the scrollHeight was greater than the clientHeight and set some state based on that. This is a simplified version of my solution.

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames'

function isOverflowed(element) {
  return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight;
}

export default class ExpandableText extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    content: PropTypes.string,
    maxHeight: PropTypes.number,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    isOpen: false,
    maxHeight: 10,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      isOpen: props.isOpen,
      isOverFlowed: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!isOverflowed(this.refs.content)) {
      this.setState({ isOpen: true, isOverFlowed: false });
    }
  }

  handleOpen() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  }

  render() {
    const { content, maxHeight } = this.props;
    const { isOpen, isOverFlowed } = this.state;
    const contentClassName = classNames('expandable-text', {
      'expandable-text__content--closed': !isOpen,
      'expandable-text__content--open': isOpen,
    });
    const actionsClassName = classNames('expandable-text__actions', { hide: !isOverFlowed })
    return (
      <div className="expandable-text">
        <div
          ref="content"
          className={contentClassName}
          style={{
            maxHeight: isOpen ? 'none' : `${maxHeight}rem`,
          }}
        >
   <p>{content}</p>
        </div>
        <div className={actionsClassName}>
          <button onClick={isOpen ? this.handleClose : this.handleOpen}>{isOpen ? 'Close': 'Open'}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So there is a decent amount going on, but the important thing is in `componentDidMount` I am checking the overflow and then setting state (potentially) based on that.

Now I realize that this could probably be accomplished by allowing a limit on number of characters instead of height, or some other solution. But if we assume the solution is similar to this, is there a more react-way to do this? (That doesn't require a rerender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine! You have to render your text before you can detect if it will overflow.

You could do some hacky stuff like counting characters/lines. But font-size can differ greatly per client, so you would just end up with a "good" guess of the overflow size.

Another thing would be to first render the text "off canvas", somehow/somewhere where the user can't see it, into a container which behaves equally to the target container. Then measure the overflow and start rendering to the actual container, knowing that it will/won't overflow.

Comment: Ya so after sleeping on it, this doesn't seem like as bad an idea as I thought. If I were to use plain JS, I probably do the same thing (concerning detecting overflow) and then append a class to the button section to hide it. Here it feels like I am rerendering the whole thing, but the vDom diffing algo should result in essentially the same thing (just the 'hide' class being added). The only thing I might change is hide it by default, so if there is any lag you don't get a flash of buttons that shouldn't exist. I am going to leave this here for a bit longer to see if anyone else contributes